# PHP - How to get page Text (plain text) on page complete load

Tags: php

how we can get TEXT ON PAGE COMPLETE LOAD

i have check following code convert html into plain text but its not up to mark.

```
$html = "<html><body>Hello <br>sjhds <br>djsds djshd <br>sdjhds </body></html>";
strip_tags(str_replace(array("<i>", "</i>"), array("_", "_"), $html));

// to preserve anchors...
str_replace("|a", "<a", strip_tags(str_replace("<a", "|a", $html)));

echo $html;
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What are you trying to do

Comment: just use `$only_text = strip_tags($html);`,  or if you want a tag ignored use `$only_text_with_a = strip_tags($html, '<a>');`

Comment: @IndraKumarS: You are right. Stripping tags is clear - but _how we can get text on page complete load_ is making me a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am worried about that it is not possible to check in PHP if page was completely loaded. In PHP you may strip tags you want - but page will be loaded after that process.

So, if you would like to strip tags after loading of page, you should use JavaScript - even like jQuery and may be also together with AJAX.